Взятие части массива
Условие: Дан массив возрастающих чисел. Даны два числа. Задача — написать метод, который из данного массива достанет ту часть, которая лежит между данными числами (включительно).
Условия выполнения: Работа с массивами. Циклы. Условные операторы (т.е. при выводе результата нельзя использовать класс Arrays)
Требуемая реализация:

Пример ввода: {1,3,5,6,9,11,24}, 4, 10
Пример вывода: [5, 6, 9]

Требования к методу:

Метод должен быть public static.
Сигнатура метода getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end.

Моя реализация кодом:
public static int[] getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    if (start < 0 || start >= numbers.length || end < start || end >= numbers.length) {
        return new int[0];
    }
    int[] subArray = new int[end - start + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
        subArray[i] = numbers[start + i];
    }
    return subArray;
}

К сожалению тесты скрыты (они крутятся на площадке в скрытом от пользователя виде), выдается только результат:

Ваш ответ не прошел тест!
Тест провален. Не корректная реализация метода getSubArrayBetween.

Собственно мой вопрос: код, что я написал вообще верен/жизнеспособен, или я что-то не так понимаю. Как в таком случае вывести все числа массива от позиции start до позиции end?

Вы свой пример запускали своим решением? Получали то, что ожидается на выходе?

Думаю, вы неверно интерпретировали задание.
Даны не индексы, а значения, и нужно извлечь часть массива с элементами, которые больше или равны start и меньше или равны end.
Для этого нужно найти индексы соответствующих элементов массива - либо линейным поиском, либо двоичным, и вычленить соответствующий диапазон, как вы уже делаете
